# Need a way to create multiple (say 250 for each) google and outlook test account for load testing oauth related apies. (Example: gmail api)

Tags: performance, testing, outlook, load, google-oauth

Scenario:
My application requires oauth google api communication. 
My current requirement is need to load test the api communication and limitations. and solution for limitations.

Expected solution:

- Need simple way to create 250 gmail accounts.
- Account should be independent from each other.
- Should require minimum individual phone numbers.

Additional req but not mandatory

- Accounts should be reusable

Thanks

Comment: It is weird that Google doesn't seem to provide any ways to create test accounts, to use solely for testing (and that they make such addresses appropriately restricted somehow). Facebook does (!). Does Google not want people to test that their Gmail integrations work. Maybe you need to buy 250 valid phone numbers.